# How can I set the SHA1 value in my debug build to be the same as the release build?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

I am building an android app using Android Studio that will connect to the Google Play API. When I run through the emulator, I get the message "The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account".

I believe the problem is that the signing certificate does not match. To get the SHA1 value to enter into the developer console, I built a release .apk, unzipped it an checked the value on it and copied into the developer console.
What I have noticed however is that if I unpack the debug apk and do the same, the value is different. Obviously this means that it will fail to connect in the emulator.

If I click Build > Generate Signed APK I can sign against my key, how can I get this to happen also for my debug builds?

Comment: You are going in completely the wrong direction. Figuring out how to make two  binaries have the same hash is not a good use of your time, and definitely not the proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: Your comment has helped me determine that I should be looking at another solution, but what I was looking to do isn't obviously wrong to me. I have been able to determine that others commonly have an additional linked app for their debug setup so I will try that, but why the down vote for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @tripleee comment, this is not the correct way to resolve this issue.

It appears that you should have 2 linked apps against your application on the developer console - one for your release app and one for your debug app with the appropriate SHA1 values for each.